# Is there a way to monitor how many open sessions in AEM instance?

Tags: aem

Right now, the website is suffering from long running open sessions problem. Sometime, I forgot to close the session after open it...I am wondering if there is a way to monitor how many open sessions are currently open in AEM instance..

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting point could be this article which specifically deals with Unclosed sessions.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/AnalyzeUnclosedSessions.html

In one of my projects i had to fix unclosed sessions throughout the codebase and the first step obviously was to find the places causing the leak.

On a unix machine the command below helped me finding the most meaningful information. the command basically does a grep on the Unclosed session warning and find the line causing it in your java or JSP code, and than sort it to list the biggest culprit at the top.

grep -h -A18 "Unclosed session detected" error.log* | grep -E "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME|org.apache.jsp" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr

hope this helps.